# Add a start index to a string index generator

Tags: python, string, generator, python-itertools

I'm currently learning to create generators and to use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). So I decided to make a string index generator, but I'd like to add some parameters such as a "start index" allowing to define where to start generating the indexes.

I came up with this ugly solution which can be very long and not efficient with large indexes:

```
import itertools
import string

class StringIndex(object):
    '''
    Generator that create string indexes in form:
    A, B, C ... Z, AA, AB, AC ... ZZ, AAA, AAB, etc.
    
    Arguments:
    - startIndex = string; default = ''; start increment for the generator.
    - mode = 'lower' or 'upper'; default = 'upper'; is the output index in
      lower or upper case.
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, startIndex = '', mode = 'upper'):
        
        if mode == 'lower':
            self.letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        
        elif mode == 'upper':
            self.letters = string.ascii_uppercase
        
        else:
            cmds.error ('Wrong output mode, expected "lower" or "upper", ' + 
                        'got {}'.format(mode))
        
        if startIndex != '':
            if not all(i in self.letters for i in startIndex):
                cmds.error ('Illegal characters in start index; allowed ' + 
                            'characters are: {}'.format(self.letters))
        
        self.startIndex = startIndex
    
    
    def getIndex(self):
        '''
        Returns:
        - string; current string index
        '''
        startIndexOk = False
        x = 1
        while True:
            strIdMaker = itertools.product(self.letters, repeat = x)
            
            for stringList in strIdMaker:
                index = ''.join([s for s in stringList])
                
                # Here is the part to simpify
                if self.startIndex:
                    if index == self.startIndex:
                        startIndexOk = True
                    
                    if not startIndexOk:
                        continue
                ###
                
                yield index
            x += 1
```

Any advice or improvement is welcome. Thank you!

**EDIT:**
The start index must be a string!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do the arithmetic (in base 26) yourself to avoid looping over `itertools.product`.  But you can at least set `x=len(self.startIndex) or 1`!

Answer (score 0):

**Old (incorrect) answer**

If you would do it without itertools (assuming you start with a single letter), you could do the following:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def getIndex(start, case):
    lets = list(letters.lower()) if case == 'lower' else list(letters.upper())
    # default is 'upper', but can also be an elif

    for r in xrange(0,10):
        for l in lets[start:]:
            if l.lower() == 'z':
                start = 0
            yield ''.join(lets[:r])+l
```

I run until max 10 rows of letters are created, but you could ofcourse use an infinite while loop such that it can be called forever.

**Correct answer**

I found the solution in a different way: I used a base 26 number translator (based on (and fixxed since it didn't work perfectly): http://quora.com/How-do-I-write-a-program-in-Python-that-can-convert-an-integer-from-one-base-to-another)

I uses itertools.count() to count and just loops over all the possibilities.

The code:

```
import time
from itertools import count

def toAlph(x, letters):
    div = 26
    r = '' if x > 0 else letters[0]
    while x > 0:
        r = letters[x % div] + r
        if (x // div == 1) and (x % div == 0):
            r = letters[0] + r
            break
        else:
            x //= div
    return r

def getIndex(start, case='upper'):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    letters = alphabet.upper() if case == 'upper' else alphabet

    started = False
    for num in count(0,1):
        l = toAlph(num, letters)
        if l == start:
            started = True

        if started:
            yield l

iterator = getIndex('AA')
for i in iterator:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Sorry  if it was unclear, but I expected the start index to be a string. Also, if the index is > 25, it seems it doesn't work. And finally, after "AZ", I get "ABA" instead of "BA".

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand you. Given the problem I think you might need something like a recursive generator cause you're essentially looping over an infinite depth tree structure.

Comment: Thank you. Still there is another issue. If I start at an index after "AAZ" I fall in an infinite loop.